For Worker In react JS
i create code at react JS side
import { Worker } from 'twilio-taskrouter';

const [worker, setWorker] = useState(null);
if (!window.TaskRouter) {
    try
    {
        console.log("Initializing TaskRouter Worker...");
        window.TaskRouterWorker = new Worker(token);
    
        window.TaskRouterWorker.on("ready", (readyAlice) => {
            console.log(`Worker ${readyAlice.sid} is now ready for work`);
        });
        setWorker(window.TaskRouterWorker);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching window.TaskRouterWorker:', error);
    } 
}
else
{
    console.log(`window.TaskRouter Not found`);
}

"Error fetching window.TaskRouterWorker: TypeError: c.default.create is not a function"
i got this error
